# When a batch and blast job is paused and resumed after some time, will it use the lastest exlcusion list or the list added during the job scheduled?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have an automation called A that daily populates a Data Extenion. This Data Extension is used as exclusion list in SFMC.

I've scheduled a batch and blast email job; having the data extension as the exclustion list

I want to pause the job when the send volume is reached for the day. When i resume the job the following day, after automation A has run, will it take the latest data extension with latest record?

Comment: In addition the sending audience is compiled first, so any changes to exclusion or sending audience would not be reflected https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_what_happens_when_you_click_send.htm&type=5

Comment: Once a job initiates sending, the data and content is locked. You would need to cancel and set up a new send. If it is in scheduled status, it is slightly different. I believe data changes can be edited if scheduled but not sending. But in either case, content changes cannot be done without cancel and recreation.